# Is there any significance to why we usually put Hillel's name before Shammai when discussing them?

Tags: beis-shammai, hillel

Is there any significance to why we usually put Hillel's name before Shammai when discussing them or is it just something that has developed that way over time?

Comment: Can you substantiate that we do in fact do that?

Comment: A [Sefaria search of "הלל ושמאי"](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%22%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%22&tab=text&tpathFilters=Mishnah|Talmud|Midrash&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) yields 22 results from Mishnah, Talmud and Midrash (287 results overall), whereas a [search of "שמאי והלל"](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%22%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9C%22&tab=text&tpathFilters=Mishnah|Talmud|Midrash&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) in the same sources yields 63 results (433 overall), for me.

Comment: In Hebrew and Aramaic we read from right to left and Hillel is usually right.

Comment: Maybe _we_ are just used to seeing it that way in [Pirkei_Avot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%22%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%22&tab=text&tpathFilters=Mishnah&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) (and don't read [Mishnah Eduyot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Eduyot.1.4?lang=bi&lang2=en), as much).

Comment: @TamirEvan If you want to give that as an answer then bli neder I'll upvote it and in the likely event that nothing better comes along (since you've made a good point), I'll accept it as the answer that I'm wrong!

Comment: See Eruvin 13b (and mefarshim there, especially Ritva) that supports @Tamir Evan re: Beis Shamai usually being mentioned before Beis Hillel (and out of that sense of modesty that's one of the reasons we say halacha k'Beis Hillel)
https://www.sefaria.org.il/Eruvin.13b.11?lang=he&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=he

Comment: Maybe because מעלין בקודש

Comment: What's your source for this? In the Mishnah, Bais Shammai is mentioned before Bais Hillel 9 times out of 10!

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the comments that my question has received and the links that I was wrong and Shammai is often mentioned before Hillel